# Google Play beta testing and publication issues

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Two days ago I've published my app on Google Play as a beta testing version and I've added a group of testers for it.
They are able to opt-in but the app is still not visible in Google Play app and from the web I can see that there are a lot of wrong information associated with it.

Current Version: Varies with device
What does this mean?

Requires Android: 1.6 and up
This is wrong as we used

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

in the manifest and

```
target=android-16
```

in project.properties

Size: Varies with device
How can I specify this info?

Moreover the google play web interface still says that this app is incompatible with the device I used to develop it! (Nexus 7).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you sure you're not uploading an incorrect manifest ?

Comment: Manifest is ok...it always worked well during the development and I can't see any relevant error.

Comment: The strange thing is that on the developer console I can see : API level 16+ that is correct! I think this could be a Google Play bug for beta test apps... :-(

Comment: Yes..that is one of the new features of Google developer console..you can publish app in alpha or beta testing before releasing to the market for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the compatibility problem with my Nexus 7.
It seems to be a bug in Google Play about supported screen sizes and about camera permission.
This is what I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="false" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: Just the first three lines (android.permission.CAMERA, android.hardware.camera, android.hardware.camera.autofocus) fixed the issue of Play Store claiming the app was incompatible with 1st gen Nexus 7 for me.  Previously was just using android.hardware.camera, which seems to default to being required, and I guess the 1st gen Nexus 7's front camera doesn't count as a canera?